# SQL GROUPING with conditional

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am sure this is easy to accomplish but after spending the whole day trying I had to give up and ask for your help.

I have a table that looks like this

```
| PatientID  | VisitId  | DateOfVisit  | FollowUp(Y/N) | FollowUpWks |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 123456789  | 2222222  |  20180802    |     Y         |     2       |
| 123456789  | 3333333  |  20180902    |     Y         |     4       |
| 234453656  | 4443232  |  20180506    |     N         |    NULL     |
| 455344243  | 2446364  |  20180618    |     Y         |    12       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically I have a list of PatientIDs, each patient can have multiple visits (VisitID and DateOfVisit). FollowUp(Y/N) specifies whether the patients has to be seen again and in how many weeks (FollowUpWks).

Now, what I need is a query that extracts PatientsID, DateOfVisit (the most recent one and only if FollowUp is YES) and the FollowUpWks field.

Final result should look like this

```
| PatientID  | VisitId  | DateOfVisit  | FollowUp(Y/N) | FollowUpWks |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 123456789  | 3333333  |  20180902    |     Y         |     4       |
| 455344243  | 2446364  |  20180618    |     Y         |    12       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The closest I could get was with this code

```
SELECT PatientID,
       Max(DateOfVisit) AS LastVisit
FROM mytable
WHERE FollowUp = True
GROUP BY PatientID;
```

The problem is that when I try adding the FollowUpWks field to the SELECT I get the following error: "The query does not include the specified expression as part of an aggregate function." However, if I add FollowUpWks to the GROUP BY statement than I get all visits, not just the most recent ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match back to the most recent visit.  One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable as t
WHERE t.FollowUp = True AND
      t.DateOfVisit = (SELECT MAX(t2.DateOfVisit)
                       FROM mytable as t2
                       WHERE t2.PatientID = t.PatientID
                      );
```